# Uncaught ReferenceError: $j is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need some help here.
this problem happens on some computer only not all.

ReferenceError'$j' is undefined
http://www.xxx.xxx/view.js:1:1Global code

```js
ReferenceError'$j' is undefined
http://www.xxxxxx.org/view.js:1:1Global code

$j(function(){
    $("form.appnitro").data('active_element','');
    var field_highlight_color = $("form.appnitro").data('highlightcolor');
    //attach event handler to all form fields, to highlight the selected list (except for matrix field)
    $("form.appnitro :input").bind('click focus',function(){
        var current_li = $(this).closest("li").not('.matrix').not('.buttons');
```

Comment: Get rid of the `j`. Really?

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code when asking a question. Try replacing $j with jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$j(function(){
```

to

```
$(function(){
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain

Comment: We need more code. How about the closing counterpart to  the above?